# Regex to allow only whitespace, letters and certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to allow only whitespace, letters, numbers and `. , ! ? ( ) $ % *`

I got something like this:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\*\(\)\?]/$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, the end of string `$` anchor should be placed inside of the delimiters. You also need to precede your character class with a [**quantifier**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#basics) and anchor the entire pattern.

The following regular expression will allow the specified characters.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,!?()$%*]+$/
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It has been a great help!